# Clicking an Edit button so I can edit a note, but the title and description don't show up

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

```
private DataGridView GetToDoListView()
{
    return toDoListView;
}

private void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, DataGridView toDoListView)
{
    isEditing = true;
    if (toDoListView != null)
    {
        titleTextBox.Text = todoList.Rows[toDoListView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].ToString();
        descriptionTextBox.Text = todoList.Rows[toDoListView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].ToString();
    }
}
```

This is my code to call back the title and description so you can edit those. But when I click, nothing actually shows up, as if I haven't clicked at all. In Visual Studio, it tells me that it's an 8602 message. And I don't know how to make this work.

I'm really new to coding, and I haven't seen anything online on how to fix it. I tried to take out the "dereference of a possibly null reference" message by using the `if (toDoListView != null)`But it hasn't worked.

Comment: It is unclear if you have tried debugging.  Have you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022

Comment: Inside your `if` block, you are assigning exactly the same expression to the `Text` of both `TextBoxes`. Why would you expect that top produce different results? You need to apply some actual logic. Think about what the code you have actually does, then then about what you actually want to do and what code would be required to do it.

Comment: `toDoListView.CurrentCell.RowIndex` is the index of the current row so `todoList.Rows[toDoListView.CurrentCell.RowIndex]` is the current row itself. Firstly, that is functionally equivalent to `toDoListView.CurrentRow`. Secondly, why would you think that calling `ToString` on a row would magically produce a value from a specific cell? If you want a value from a cell then you have to get the cell first, then get the value from it. That's the logic involved that you haven't thought through before writing your code. Logical steps first, then code to impalement those specific steps.

Comment: Are you initialising `toDoListView` anywhere? If so, please edit that code into your question. If you're not then that's why it's not working.